# UnauthorizedAccessException on reading file

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, asp.net-web-api, io

I have and ASP Web API and I'm trying to return a file from a call there.

On my server I keep getting the error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   'E:\Data\Docs\specific\document.pdf' is denied.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode)    at
>   GIS.Backend.Assets.BLL.Document.GetByUrl(String url)    at
>   GIS.Backend.Assets.WebApi.Controllers.DocumentController.Get(String
>   url)

I'm guessing this is where it goes wrong:

```
string documentenPath = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentenDir"].ToString();
        string fullUrl = documentenPath + url;

        Stream file = new FileStream(fullUrl, FileMode.Open);
        return file;
```

I have set IIS_IUSRS to have read access to the 'Docs' folder, so it should be able to read right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

open the Stream with the FileAccess.Read flag

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullUrl, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Answer (score 0):

`File.Open` also needs a `FileAccess.Read` or a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` exception will be thrown by the server

```
FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(fullUrl, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```